# Mass of a wire: intersection of surfaces

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

So I got this mass problem to solve:
Find the mass of the wire formed by the intersection of two surfaces whose density is 
$\phi=x²$

$\underset{C}\int \phi ds $ along the curve:

$$
C:\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x²+y²+z²=1 \\ 
x+y+z=0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

My question is not exactly in how to solve this - because I know how to solve it as my calculus teacher taught - but in how(if it can be solved that way) to solve it using **linear algebra**. It's just an effort I'm trying to do to integrate what I've learned in both courses in this semester so It might be just a dumb idea.
I started by backsubstitution and got this equation of the intersection $$ 2x²+ 2xy + 2y² =1 $$ which I identify as a quadratic form, rewrote it in matrix form and diagonalized it. The elipsoid at the new "u v frame" is: $$ 3u² + v² = 1$$
whose parametrization is: $$ \gamma(t)=((1/\sqrt3)cos(t), sin(t)) $$
then I found the norm of the derivative as to substitute ds at the line integral $ ds=||\gamma'(t)||dt $

But now things started to get confusing and **here's my problem I think**

I don't know if I'm right but it seems I can't just compose $\phi(x)$ with $ \gamma(t) $ and proceed finding the primitive as $\phi=x²$ is in the "x y frame". At my humble opinion it seems that I should rotate somehow this density function as to find it's equation in the "u v frame".

- Is it possible?
- Is it practicle?
- Am I proceeding right until now?

Sorry for any problems at my question, first time here;

Cheers.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you combine the two equations to find the intersection, you missed one variable $z$. So what you found is the projection of the intersection onto $xy$-plane. To make it really the intersection, you have to add an equation that represent the $z$-value. For example, you can add $z=-x-y$ and add that into your parametric equation.

After your represent the curve in parametric equation, you can represent $\phi=x^2$ using the $x$ component of the curve.

Comment: Thx! That seems right, missed that z coordinate, but the problem still remains =) I'll correct it!

Comment: @MarceloBroinizi: The problem is you cannot represent the intersection curve using one equation. For the representation of $\phi$, see my edited answer.

Comment: Got that, but don't think u really understood what I asked: my parametrization is for the u v frame so I think I might have to find out how does density behaves in u direction instead of x direction. It doesn't seem to make sense composing the "x" of phi with a parametrization for - applying your correction - u, v, w plane.
If it's really ok to do that it means the density is a invariant which is really strange for me.

Comment: @MarceloBroinizi: I see what you meant now. Yes, you will need to do a rotation to transform the ellipse. I think Stewart's book explains it clearly: http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/ESSENTIAL%20CALCULUS/upfiles/topics/ess_at_13_ra_stu.pdf. But I doubt whether it worth the extra effort to do that. Looks to me the polar coordinates would work well with $x,y$ values.

Comment: Yes, you almost got now! ahaha! I did it, I found a good frame so the elipse now seems really nice to work, the problem is that I should also "rotate" somehow the x² by the same angle I rotated the elipse. But I don't know if I can in fact rotate a polynomial function in that way as it would become non-surjective; I'll try posting a picture.

Comment: @MarceloBroinizi: Remember you are integration this function $\phi$ along the curve that is defined in $3$D. So the function $x^2$ is not in the $xy$-plane. It is a function in terms of the $x$-value. If you want to draw it, you have to draw it in the space. So the rotation does not put $x^2$ in the $uv$-plane. It is still a function in the space that depends on $uv$.